# Google Plus Android GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() Equivalent for iOS

Tags: android, ios, authentication, google-plus, google-oauth

What is the iOS equivalent for Android GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() using Google OAuth 2.0 iOS SDK 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS, the way to get the CODE that can be obtained with getToken() onAndroid is

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;
```

In the method

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error
```

This will return a "one use" CODE that looks like

```
4/8jjD0KiC2iCqhb6VL5FQ8Q.ckOA0UAc0hQR3oEBd8DOtNDVtIApkgI
```

This CODE would be passed to the server from the app if the server would need to do Google API calls on behalf of the App User.

If the server does not need to do Google API calls then the JWT ID TOKEN could be passed to the server for Login Authentication.

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].idToken;
```

on iOS this is a BASE 64 ish encoded Json.  Can decode it with code from here...

http://popdevelop.com/2013/12/decode-json-web-token-jwt-in-ios-objective-c/